# custom height for rounded rectangle UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitextfield

I have UITextField of type RoundedRectangle. I want to set height to 50.

When I tried through IB, I see its disabled. When I change the type to rectangle, I see it enabled and I can change from there. I changed to 50 and changed the type again to RoundedRectangle. It again become, 30 height.

Any idea, how this can be done? Any help/ suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does you question title say "..rounded rectangle button" but in your question it says "..`UITextField` of type RoundedRectangle.." which is it button or text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the textfield type to square rectangle in IB and set height to 50 and in code in viewDidLoad just say

```
[firstName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be one of those odd-balls that IB doesn't cater for well.  A bit like setting rounded corners on UITextField et al.

Set up an IBOutlet for the button and connect it with an instance var/property in your .h file for the view and then use something like:

```
myButton.frame.size.height = 50.0;
```

This should work because UITextField is a descendent of UIView which has frame, frame is a CGRect and CGRect contains structures for origin and size.

You specify sizings as CGFloat which are decimal numbers.

Further reference: [CGRect Documentation in UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect)

Comment: this don't happen when default style is Rounded Rectange.

Comment: As stated in next answer then, set height inside IB and then in code apply the UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect to it.